# Hyperledger Chaincode query is successful but doesn't return result through Java SDK

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I have a fabric network running on my machine.

1. When I tried deploying, instantiating, adding some data to ledger and fire chaincode query through CLI, It works fine and returns the expected response with bootstraped data.
2. When I try to deploy, instantiate using Java SDK (version 1.1),
   It gives success response, but when I try to fire chaincode query with admin context and same params as in 1. (Ref: https://github.com/IBM/blockchain-application-using-fabric-java-sdk/tree/master/java/src/main/java/org/app/chaincode/invocation),
   it doesn't fail but returns empty response. What's going wrong here?
   How can I fix this?

To add more detail:
Here are the docker chaincode container logs for both 1 and 2 cases:

1. ccResolverWrapper: sending new addresses to cc: [{user1.example.io:7051 0  }]
2. ccResolverWrapper: sending new addresses to cc: [{user1.example.io:7052 0  }]

The CLI one sends request to 7051 (which works) , however Java SDK case sends it to 7052 (doesn't work)
port. Can this be the issue? How can I try to change it to 7051 in case of Java SDK (2.)?